# How to combine do_action along with str_replace?

Tags: php, wordpress, replace

I have a `do_action` function in a template page that activates the "Posts Per Cat" plugin that lists my posts in certain categories on a page.

It shows up only the posts titles, but I would like to make break line and italic in my titles, which I can do using `str_replace`.

But I don't know how to use it in conjunction with my `do_action` function. When the `do_action` function calls my post's title, I would like it to format the titles as I have set it up in my `str_replace` function.

**This is the code to activate the plugin function:**

```html
<?php do_action('ppc'); ?>
```

**This is the code to replace particular characters of my posts' titles into break line and italic:**

```html
<?php $first = str_replace(' | ', '<br />', get_the_title()); 
      echo str_replace('REPLACE_ME', '<i>REPLACE_ME</i>', $first);?>
```

They don't work together like this and I don't know how to combine them. Actually, I think the `str_replace` shouldn't call `get_the_title` because the `do_action` of my plugin already calls the titles, but I don't know how to manage this.

**Here is an example of a title :**

ALLEINANSPRUCH Arne Schmitt, Nico Joana Weber 4 Februar – 30 April 2017

**And the expected result:**

ALLEINANSPRUCH

Arne Schmitt, Nico Joana Weber

*4 Februar – 30 April 2017*

**I have been trying this, but it doesn't work, it just repeats the action of the plugin, but doesn't format the text.**

```html
<?php
/*
Template Name: Ausstellungen
*/
?>

<?php get_header(); ?>

<div class="container">
  <?php do_action('ppc');?>
  <?php $first = str_replace(' | ', '<br />', do_action('ppc')); 
        echo str_replace('REPLACE_ME', '<i>REPLACE_ME</i>', $first);?>
</div>
```

Comment: If you want the title (with ' | ' replaced with '<br />') wrapped in an italic tag, why not just use: echo "<i>$first</i>";

Comment: The code I use for str_replace works well. But now, I need to use it with this do_action code that you can see on my post. My issue is that I don't know how to use it in conjunction with my do_action code. Basically, how to combine those two codes together and have both of them doing what they should do.

Comment: @chrlaura , The idea would be to get something like this but it doesn't make the job : `<?php $first = str_replace(' | ', '<br />', do_action('ppc')); echo str_replace('REPLACE_ME', '<i>REPLACE_ME</i>', $first);?>` It just repeats the action, but doesn't format the text.

Comment: Can you include the entire code in the question? And an example of a title? And the expected result for that particular title?

Comment: @chrlaura I have updated my question

Comment: How does the ppc function look?

Comment: As it is pasted at the beginning of my question, I don't have more than that from the plugin.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153467/discussion-between-chrlaura-and-lolo).